# Regarding OpenSSL command RSA key generation(128 bit)

Tags: openssl, hex, rsa

I'm using OpenSSL version 1.0.2j

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
```

I generate a 32 bit key for learning purpose:

```
$ openssl genrsa -out key.pem 32; openssl rsa -in key.pem -text -noout
Generating RSA private key, 32 bit long modulus
.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
e is 65537 (0x10001)
Private-Key: (32 bit)
modulus: 3049905109 (0xb5c9dbd5)
publicExponent: 65537 (0x10001)
privateExponent: 643259637 (0x26575cf5)
prime1: 59747 (0xe963)
prime2: 51047 (0xc767)
exponent1: 34201 (0x8599)
exponent2: 28991 (0x713f)
coefficient: 570 (0x23a)
```

I tested 59747 * 51047 == 3049905109, so that is correct.

Then I tried to generate 128 bits:

```
$ openssl genrsa -out key.pem 128; openssl rsa -in key.pem -text -noout
Generating RSA private key, 128 bit long modulus
.....+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
e is 65537 (0x10001)
Private-Key: (128 bit)
modulus:
    00:d7:f5:7b:f4:ac:b3:d6:ab:69:e9:f8:46:89:80:
    ad:a7
publicExponent: 65537 (0x10001)
privateExponent:
    00:96:69:0e:9d:5a:0f:a3:49:d5:f2:7f:5b:d5:bd:
    d5:71
prime1: 4077820879 (0xf30e9bcf)
prime2: 1063358121 (0x3f618ea9)
exponent1: 843651503 (0x324919af)
exponent2: 245467033 (0xea18799)
coefficient: 3957324193 (0xebdff9a1)
```

Clearly 0xf30e9bcf * 0x3f618ea9 = 3C2D38538980ADA7, but the modulus is 00d7f57bf4acb3d6ab69e9f8468980ada7.

Looks like the last 8 hexadecimal digits are correct, but others are not the same. I'm confused why this would happen. Can someone kindly explain?

Answer (score 2):

The printing command seems to have gotten confused, and it printed `prime1` and `prime2` (and friends) as 32-bit values instead of 64-bit values.

The [factorization of `D7F57BF4ACB3D6AB69E9F8468980ADA7`](https://www.numberempire.com/numberfactorizer.php?number=287058645945599681238703853074303200679) is `F798F9F1F30E9BCF` * `DF49A5063F618EA9`.

The OpenSSL command printed the bottom 32 bits of each of the prime factors, instead of the full 64 bits.

Since there's no mod in this multiplication the bottom 32 bits of the result are correct with the trimmed values, just due to multiplication.  (Think back to writing out the multiplication of two long numbers in long form... now do it in hexadecimal).

I ran the command a goodly number of times, and it always printed 64-bit values of the CRT values:

```
$ openssl genrsa 128 | openssl rsa -text
Generating RSA private key, 128 bit long modulus
.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
...+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
e is 65537 (0x10001)
Private-Key: (128 bit)
modulus:
    00:e9:e2:0f:ed:54:89:0c:e7:4c:a0:c5:52:8f:c3:
    85:c3
publicExponent: 65537 (0x10001)
privateExponent:
    00:b5:bc:a8:dd:a5:3b:9d:9e:bd:80:57:b6:b2:ff:
    f3:d1
prime1: 17667776196693030377 (0xf5308cd7cefd75e9)
prime2: 17596097080145549003 (0xf431e510f75d16cb)
exponent1: 10532946027144870681 (0x922c8a9b1254fb19)
exponent2: 7661660226727396529 (0x6a53af620bd344b1)
coefficient: 1528899226626897395 (0x1537bdbf047735f3)
writing RSA key
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MGMCAQACEQDp4g/tVIkM50ygxVKPw4XDAgMBAAECEQC1vKjdpTudnr2AV7ay//PR
AgkA9TCM1879dekCCQD0MeUQ910WywIJAJIsipsSVPsZAghqU69iC9NEsQIIFTe9
vwR3NfM=
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Digging further into it, it looks like the problem happens on 64-bit systems when `long` is still 32-bit.

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_2j/crypto/asn1/t_pkey.c#L82-L87:

```
if (BN_num_bytes(num) <= BN_BYTES) {
    if (BIO_printf(bp, "%s %s%lu (%s0x%lx)\n", number, neg,
                   (unsigned long)num->d[0], neg,
                   (unsigned long)num->d[0])
        <= 0)
        return (0);
```

`BN_BYTES` is 8 on systems where [SIXTY_FOUR_BIT_LONG or SIXTY_FOUR_BIT](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_2j/crypto/bn/bn.h) was defined during configuration.

```
$ grep SIXTY_FOUR `locate opensslconf.h | grep ^/usr`
#define SIXTY_FOUR_BIT_LONG
#undef SIXTY_FOUR_BIT
```

Since I'm `SIXTY_FOUR_BIT_LONG` my printing command works for the 33- to 64-bit range.

```
$ uname -srmo
Linux 4.4.0-119-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ head -2 /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.4 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! It seems that on Windows, long is 32 bits. That's why it display only the bottom 32 bits.